# Errors during import of sql file to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to database and have just started to learn MYSQL. I have downloaded a sql file called rating.sql and would like to import it to the MYSQL database installed on the local machine. The operation system is Windows 7. The path for the sql file is:

```
"E:\rating.sql".
```

I am using the following commands in the MySQL Command Line Client

```
mysql>use database_name;
mysql>source E:\rating.sql;
```

The system gives the following error message:

```
ERROR 1049 <42000>: Unknown database 'ating.sql'
```

It is definitely  something related to the path. Can anyone explain how this error is generated?Thanks

Comment: You need to escape the \

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee - show how to do it....

Comment: @NigelNquande I am using Eclipse and has connected MySQL DB to Eclipse using a connector. I am doing all query in the Eclipse environment. Is  this normal in industry or everybody in Industry uses the MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have use \ and this is an escape character (omits the immediate following character. So to fix this you can use \ instead.

```
mysql>resour E:\\rating.sql;
```

Comment: @NigelNquande my level is not high enough to allow me to do that. It requires level 15 and I am only 11.

Comment: No, that's to give rep. To accept the answer just click the tick not the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql recognises `\r` as an escape for a carriage return character.

To make it simpler, could you rename your file to something beginning with another letter...mustn't be b n r t or z...

Comment: Renaming the file isn't the right solution, to my mind. Escaping the path separator is a better solution.